# Do you know of a good quick reference guide for a number of programming languages?

Tags: programming-languages, reference

In the course of my job I am maintaining code in a number of programming languages (listed below). As I haven't mastered most of them I keep forgetting the differences in syntax between them. Is there a good reference which covers (preferably for all of them on a side of A4, in a table) the basic features of the language e.g.

- conditional statements (if (something)
  {} or not?)
- comparison operators (is it =, ==, or sometimes ===? Is it <> or !=)
- Are variables case sensitive?
- How do you concatenate strings? ( . & or + ?)

I would like this for:

- Python
- PHP
- Perl
- Javascript
- ASP

Comment: Well, we could make this community wiki and create a reference table ourselves by editing it.

Comment: yeap, I can help with php and classic asp stuff...

Comment: Started a community wiki answer. Feel free to edit and fill the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://rigaux.org/language-study/syntax-across-languages/ has more languages than you want, but at least it is focused on syntax. No single page, either.

Comment: I'm choosing this one because it's nearest to what I want. It does have a single page too
http://merd.sourceforge.net/pixel/language-study/syntax-across-languages.html
I'm going to cut it down to just the languages I want, and for functions, add arguments as they are missing.

http://rosettacode.org/blog/2009/06/a-mashup-challenge.html looked hopeful - I could take the XML output and with an XSL stylesheet extract just the languages I wanted. However that output isn't working, and even if it was it wouldn't be up to date.

Answer (score 5):

[DZone](http://refcardz.dzone.com/home?page=3&oid=ban00021-0) has quite a few.

Comment: +1 From me. It is very complete.

Answer (score 4):

Please feel free to fill in.

```
                           Python       PHP       Perl           JavaScript    VBScript    

Conditional Statements

Comparison Operators
  basic                    ==           ==       ==              ==            =
                           <>           !=       !=              !=            <>
  typesafe                 n/a          ===      n/a             ===           n/a
                           n/a          !==      n/a             !(===)        n/a

Variables case sensitive?  yes          yes       yes            yes           no

Concatenate strings with   +            .,(,)     .              +             &
                           string.join            join "a", "b"
```

Comment: When I said ASP, I meant VBScript, so if someone could amend the table when they next go in that would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Main_Page is your friend :)

Answer (score 3):

I would start by looking for programming cheat sheets. Here's [one pretty good selection](http://webdeveloper.econsultant.com/cheat-sheets/).

Answer (score 2):

gotapi is a nice place

http://www.gotapi.com/html

I would definetely have a look at it

you should also visit dzone's refcardz

http://refcardz.dzone.com/

they have a lot of useful reference cards...

like this one

http://refcardz.dzone.com/announcements/php

Answer (score 2):

http://pleac.sourceforge.net/ this one is good to :)

Answer (score 1):

**PHP:**

**Conditional statements**

- if ($cond)
- $cond ? $value_if_true : $value_if_false;

**Comparison operators**

PHP supports the following basic comparison operators:

- ==
- !=

It also contains type-safe operators:

- ===
- !==

Expressions can be negated using the unary ! operator.

**Boolean operators**

The basic boolean operators are:

- && / and
- || / or

**Case sensitivity**

PHP variables are case sensitive. So are associative array keys.

**String concatenation**

. (dot) is used for string concatenation in PHP.

Comment: I added some additional info. Anyone that wants to add another language can feel free to use this as a template. Also, feel free to add additional reference info.

Answer (score 1):

asp classic:

**Conditional statements**

if (cond) then

else

end if

**Comparison operators**

ASP classic supports the following basic comparison operators:

=

!=

Expressions can be negated using the unary ! operator.

**Boolean operators**

The basic boolean operators are:

and

or

not

**Case sensitivity**

ASP classic variables are NOT case sensitive.

**String concatenation**

& (ampersand) is used for string concatenation, you can also use "+".