# BeautifulSoup quick reference guide

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I love BeautifulSoup, but I use it so infrequently that I'm always forgetting the commands/syntax. The [tutorial](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) is great, but I'd really love to find a one-page, printable quick-reference guide or cheat sheet (like the ones [here](http://devcheatsheet.com/) and [here](http://www.cheat-sheets.org/)). Have any of you ever found one or made one?

UPDATE: I've begun trying to create one myself, but I can't imagine I'm the first person to make one, and I'd prefer not to duplicate the wheel. Plus, I'm no expert, so I'd love to get a more reliable source.

Comment: This question does not belong here

Comment: @user1833746, before posting I searched SO and found several similar questions (e.g. [[1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/491312/is-there-a-wpf-cheat-sheet-available)], [[2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026508/do-you-know-of-a-good-quick-reference-guide-for-a-number-of-programming-language)], [[3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1154382/anyone-have-an-erd-symbols-quick-reference)], [and many others](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=cheat+sheet)), many of which were upvoted significantly. So I deemed it an appropriate question for this venue.

Comment: Making it yourself would probably be really helpful, like making a notecard to use on a test